How to request a URL every minute with Curl in Windows?
I would like some advice, am trying to request a URL every 1 minute to feed keep track of a computers uptime
I have tried to use a bat file with the below:
curl https://example.com timeout /t 60 loop

It opens the link as expected however won’t repeat again.
Can anyone help or suggest a better way?
I just need to request a URL every 1 minute, don't need a page to show and as discrete as possible.

To do a loop, you need to use for do. You can use something like this in a batch file:
for /l %%i in () do @curl https://example.com & timeout /t 60

You can surpress the response from the webpage by using the -s -o switchs and redirecting the outpul to nul:
for /l %%i in () do @curl -s -o nul https://example.com & timeout /t 60

